# HTML link in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I put a html button link in my PHP IF function?

It looks like this:

```
<?php
    if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] ==  $product["user_id"]){
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cadeau bewerken"></input> </a>
    }
?>
```

But obviously, it won't work because I have html code in it.
What is another way to do it?

Comment: button inside anchor is invalid HTML5 according to the HTML5 Spec Document from W3C: http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: Why dont you style your anchor as a button?

Comment: You should name filename and class name Kdgwcontroller is the correct codeigniter way not KdGwController https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically do it in two ways. First:

### UPDATE:

#### The comment made by [@Vickel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957597/html-link-in-php/46957794#comment80862910_46957597) is completely right! So I'm editing your html to what it should be.

Echoing a string:

```
<?php
    if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] ==  $product["user_id"]){
        // Wrong html
        // echo '<a href="'. base_url() . '/KdGwController/details_bewerken/' . $product->product_id . '"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cadeau bewerken"></input> </a>';
        // Right html
        echo '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="'. base_url() . '/KdGwController/details_bewerken/' . $product->product_id . '"> Cadeau bewerken </a>';
    }  
?>
```

Second. Closing the PHP:

```
<?php
    if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] ==  $product["user_id"]){
?>
        <!-- Wrong html -->
        <!-- <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cadeau bewerken"></input> </a> -->
        <!-- Right html -->
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"> Cadeau bewerken </a>

<?php
        }  
?>
```

I personally prefer the second because of the syntax highlight. An ever better way of doing this would be using the ["syntax sugar if"](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php):

```
<?php if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] ==  $product["user_id"]): ?>
    <!-- Wrong html -->
    <!-- <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cadeau bewerken"></input> </a> -->
    <!-- Right html -->
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"> Cadeau bewerken </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

You could do this :

```
<?php   
    if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] ==  $product["user_id"]){ 
?>
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/KdGwController/details_bewerken/<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cadeau bewerken"></input> </a>
<?php
    }  
?>
```

Or alternatively, have PHP `echo` or `print()` the html tag. (which is somewhat cleaner, but requires that you escape your `"` characters)

```
<?php   
    if ( $_SESSION['user_id'] ==  $product["user_id"]){ 
        echo "<a href=\"".base_url()."/KdGwController/details_bewerken/".$product->product_id."\"><input type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" value=\"Cadeau bewerken\"></input> </a>";
    }  
?>
```

Comment: also, it's kinda weird to put a `<button>` inside an `<a>`. are you sure you're doing the right thing there?